# Module returns multiple functions

Tags: functions, scoping

I want to write a module that returns two functions which then can be evaluated later on. I know how to do it with a single function, but I don't know how to make it work for multiple functions.

An example for the single function case:

```
prep[p1_, p2_] := Module[{},
f1[x_, y_] := (p1 + p2)*x + y;
f1[#1, #2] &
];
myfunc = prep[1, 2];
myfunc[1, 3]
```

For this input myfunc returns 6 as expected. Now what I would like to have is not a single function returned but multiple (for example two). I have tried to do the following

```
prep[p1_, p2_] := Module[{},
f1[x_, y_] := (p1 + p2)*x + y;
f2[x_, y_] := (p1 - p2)*x - y;
{f1[#1, #2],f2[#3,#4]} &
];
{myfunc1,myfunc2} = prep[1, 2];
```

but I get an error saying that the two lists are different (which is somewhat understandable).

Is there a simple way to return multiple functions in a similar way?

Comment: Try `myDoubleFunc = prep[1, 2]; myDoubleFunc[1, 2, 3, 4]`. This will return a list of two elements, each one being the result of evaluation of `f1` and `f2`, respectively.

Comment: Isn't there a way to assign them individually?

Comment: Sure, but you need to change the definition inside the module. Change the return value to `{f1, f2}` inside Module, then call it as `{myFunc1, myFunc2} = prep[1, 2];` and then you can use them independently.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you, now it works. Can you explain the difference between returning myFunc[#] and simply myFunc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
prep[p1_, p2_] := Module[{},
   f1[x_, y_] := (p1 + p2)*x + y;
   f2[x_, y_] := (p1 - p2)*x - y;
   {f1, f2}];
```

Then:

```
{myfunc1, myfunc2} = prep[1, 2];
```

And e.g.:

```
myfunc1[10, 20]
myfunc2[10, 20]

(*50,-30*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prep[p1_, p2_] := Module[{}, f1[x_, y_] := (p1 + p2)*x + y;
f2[x_, y_] := (p1 - p2)*x - y;
{f1[#1, #2] &, f2[#1, #2] &}];
{myfunc1, myfunc2} = prep[1, 2];
 myfunc1[1, 2]
 myfunc2[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would forgo the whole Module thing:

```
prep[p1_, p2_] := 
  {Function[{x, y}, (p1 + p2)*x + y], Function[{x, y}, (p1 - p2)*x - y]}
```

Then:

```
prep[a, b][[1]][x, y]
(* (a+b) x+y *)
```

and

```
{f1, f2} = prep[a, b]
(* {Function[{x$,y$},(a+b) x$+y$],Function[{x$,y$},(a-b) x$-y$]} *)

f1[x, y]
(* (a+b) x+y *)
```

This way you don't litter your session with stray DownValues for f1,f2.

I'm a bit concerned that in your original attempt you used `#1`,`#2`,`#3`,and `#4`, which suggests that you actually want `prep` to return a function of four inputs (which in turn returns a list of two values when evaluated). If that's the case, then the answer would be different.

Comment: How should I change this prep function if I not only want to return the list of functions, but also carry out some other calculations?

Comment: I'm sure there are myriad ways to do that. It would help to know what other calculations you want to do. If they're not relevant to this question, post a different one.